rspec describe/context label within loop not working
Hi there
Because i cannot distinguish if i am wrong or if this is a bug i opened a bug report too.
I need to have a describe/context block within a loop and I am facing a totally strange behavior at the point when I want to access a variable from outside the Rspec.describe block.
Its an app with many different user roles that need to be tested. Idea is to have a central variable with all user roles (e.g. [:staff, :company_lead, ...]) and within the request-specs I want to iterate it.
rspec-core (3.12.2, 3.12.1)
rspec-rails (6.1.0, 6.0.1)
rails 6.1
ruby 2.7.2
I tested the same on a newer app (ruby 3.2.2, rails 7.0.5, rspec-rails 6.0.1), but same behaviour. But, on examples like GitHub 2010 this seemed to work many years ago.
This works
RSpec.describe '/admin/settings', type: :request do
    
    ALLOWED_ROLES = %i[adm bo_adm]
    
    ALLOWED_ROLES.each do |role|
    describe "allowed as #{role}" do
      login("user_#{role}")
        it "check" do
          expect(1).to eq(2)
        end
    end
  end
end

Tests are failing, like expected.
This works too
class Tests
  SUBTESTS = [:adm, :bo_adm]
end

RSpec.describe '/admin/settings', type: :request do
  Tests::SUBTESTS.each do |v|
      context "as_role_" do
        it "check" do
          expect(1).to eq(2)
        end
      end
    end
end

=> tests are running and failing, but problem: i do not see which subtest is failing because the context label is always the same
This crashes
class Tests
  SUBTESTS = [:adm, :bo_adm]
end

RSpec.describe '/admin/settings', type: :request do
  Tests::SUBTESTS.each do |v|
      context "as_role_#{v}" do
        it "check" do
          expect(1).to eq(2)
        end
      end
    end
end

At the point where I include the variable v in the context label, the tests are crashing, it says "No tests were found ... All examples have been filtered out".
I do nothing different than in the first test, which works except dragging the array (Tests::SUBTESTS) from outside the Rspec.describe block where the tests reside.
Am I missing something?
Is there another way for doing this?
Currently I have /spec/support/controller_macros.rb where all the login_as... methods are defined. There I want to put an array with all user roles and access it from all specs that are inside /spec/requests/.... But I cannot find a way to make this working.
Thanks,
Chris

I am unable to reproduce your issue Example using your exact test body.

Thanks @engineersmnky may it be related to my environment ...? On wich environment you are? I am on MAC Sonoma 14.4.1

This is not going to be environment dependent. You say "the tests are crashing". Crash usually suggests an error. Is there an Error? Can you provide a stacktrace? Are you certain your example is the same as your code?

Thanks @engineersmnky I may have found a trace: When I run the test on RubyMine (by mouseclick), it crashes, but when I run the exact same test by console, it works, so it may be related to the RubyMine UI.

i created a issue on Jetbrains

I don't think you're neccissarily wrong. You're just overlooking that RSpec already has shared examples which is most likely a better solution.
